# ESP32: Count backwards asynchronously

Tags: c++, asynchronous, timer, esp32

I've written a little program which counts back from 5 to 0 and does a println afterwards. I've wrapped this a little bit, but please let me show my code:

Main.ino

```
#include "MyObject.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

MyObjekt *myObject;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  string trigger = "triggering";
  myObject = new MyObject(trigger);
}
void loop(){}
```

MyObject.h

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyObject{
  public: 
    string field;

    MyObject(string trigger);
    
    string GetField(){ return field; }
    void SetField(string trigger);
};

#endif
```

MyObject.cpp

```
#include "MyObject.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "Timer.h"

MyObject::MyObject(string trigger){
    SetField(trigger);
}
void MyObject::SetField(string trigger){

    field = trigger;

    auto f = []() {std::cout << "---------------- I waited to print! ----------------\n"; };
    Timer t1{10000,f};
}
```

Timer.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Timer {
public:
    Timer(size_t time, const std::function<void(void)>& f) : time{std::chrono::milliseconds{time}}, f{f} {}
    ~Timer() {wait_thread.join();}

private:
    void wait_then_call()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{mtx};
        for(int i{5}; i > 0; --i) {
            //std::cout << "Thread " << wait_thread.get_id() << " countdown at: " << '\t' << i << '\n';
            cv.wait_for(lck, time / 10);
        }
        f();
    }
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv{};
    std::chrono::milliseconds time;
    std::function <void(void)> f;
    std::thread wait_thread{[this]() {wait_then_call();}};
};
```

Unfortately this blocks the main thread, so nothing other (like another println) is done during this. Is it somehow possible to do this countdown in the background and only do the println (`f` ) in the foreground (in other words: listening while doing work, if background-println is detected/sent to listener, execute, then listen again and continue with work)?

Would be really happy about every answer and help effort. Sorry if for my Problems expressing myself, i hope it became somehow clear what I am trying to achieve^^

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on Arduino. Using the [arduino-timer](https://github.com/contrem/arduino-timer) library, the code should look something similar:

```
#include <arduino-timer.h>

const size_t TIMER_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;
volatile int counter = 5;
auto timer = timer_create_default();

void setup() {
    timer.every(TIMER_INTERVAL_MS, [](void*) -> bool { counter--; return true; });
}

void loop() {
    timer.tick();
    if (counter <= 0) {
        Serial.println("Counter is 0");
        counter = 5; // Reset counter
}
```

Sorry, can't validate or run the code as I don't have an Arduino setup ready to go. But you should get the point.

You can also do more complex solutions like ask the timer peripheral for an interrupt; or set up timer service in the RTOS (assuming you've upgraded to one). The basic principle is the same.

Comment: Hello @Tarmo and thank you so much for your help effort. I installed the recommended library, added `Serial.begin(9600);` at the begin and uploaded your code, but this unfortunately had no effect, so the line `Serial.println("Counter is 0");` is not printed :( Concerning your hint with RTOS i found amongst others this tutorial: [link](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/05/06/esp32-arduino-creating-a-task/), but as I am only a student there were again some questions risen: do I have to put all my main logic and program in the taskOne and the backwards counting function into taskTwo? Best regards

Comment: You can debug my code by sprinkling a few printf-s to tell you what's happening. Likely there is an error in my implementation as I haven't used this library. Maybe the lambda has to return a true instead of false (corrected). I was just trying to demostrate the general approach to timers and how simple they are. If working with FreeRTOS, it's quite impractical to create a dedicated task just to count down. A [software timer](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-software-timer.html) would be more useful. See [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-and-using-freertos-software-timers).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use keyword `new` if you never call `delete`, as it would cause memory leak. What do you want can be achieved with two ways:

**1. Use Counter**

This is still run on the loopTask, but it is let other code to run.

```
long lastMillis = 0;
long interval = 1000;
long counter = 5;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (millis() - lastMillis > interval && counter >= 0) {
    lastMillis = millis();
    Serial.println(counter--);
  }

  //Other code would still run
}
```

**2. Create Another Task**

This would be completely asynchronous, even if you are calling delay() on the other task, the code on the loopTask would still run.

```
int counter = 5;
int interval = 1000;

void vTask(void *param) {
  while (counter >= 0) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(counter--);
  }
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  xTaskCreate(vTask, "vTask", 4096, NULL, 1, NULL);
}

void loop() {}
```